# Content following after jquery, bouncing instead of flowing

Tags: html, list, jquery-ui, effect

What's wrong?
Content following the jquery script is not flowing to it's relative position on jquery click. Instead it is bouncing.

http://jsfiddle.net/sywgrkep/1/

```
<div>hey you</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Jquery [.slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) function.

```
$("#pfcontainer_inner_phead_clicker").click(function () {
        $("#pfcontainer_inner_phead_slider").slideToggle(200);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sywgrkep/3/